# Angular - How to correctly import md5 hash in Angular 2 typescript file?

Tags: javascript, angular, hash

I tried to use md5 hash for hashing user password in Angular 2, but for some reason when I run my application Md5 module is not recognized.
[image]

I have also imported it in typescript file like this:
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

For me it's weird that Md5 is recognized in Visual Studio, but in Google Chrome I get error as you can see on picture. So my question is where is the mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: are you using systemJS?

Comment: you mean systemjs.config.js? I'm new to Angular 2 and I don't fully understand what is systemJS

Comment: yeah systemjs.config.js

Comment: yes, I'm using it. Do I have to put something related to md5 in systemjs?

Comment: yeah, I posted an answer below that should work for you.

Comment: [Our password hashing has no clothes](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using systemJS (systemjs.config) then in that file you will need to include:

```
map:   {
          'ts-md5': 'node_modules/ts-md5',
       }
packages: {
          'ts-md5': {main: '/md5.js'},                
       }
```

Look for both 'map' and 'packages' inside of systemjs.config and then include 'ts-md5' in them. This will tell the app where to look for those files.

Also make sure that you have installed it first using `npm install ts-md5 --save`

Comment: I'll try it now. Hopefully my problem will be solved :). If this works your answer will be accepted.

Comment: I get the same error. This doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately without seeing more of the code it is hard to say what the issue is. But basically that error means it can't find ts-md5 package at all. Are you using node_modules or did you just copy the files into your project?

Comment: I'm using node_modules and ts-md5 is stored in node_modules/ts-md5/dist/md5.
I have installed it using npm.

Comment: oh actually I think I know the issue. Inside of the 'map' from above try changing the path to: `node_modules/ts-md5/dist`

Comment: I have found what was bothering my Chrome. It was stupid cache memory. Your answer for 'map' without '/dist' was correct. Thank you very much!